# Get PDF page size with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I have a PDF document that I just received via file upload (InputFile).

I'd like to use iTextSharp to check it's page size before proceeding.  For example, the size of a pdf when you go to file > Properties > Description Tab > Page Size (in acrobat).

Any advice on how I can do that?

THANKS!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to read the pdf from your input stream (m).

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(m);
// Page size
Rectangle pagesize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
```

Comment: i'm struging get this done. what is the writer object here.. (i'm new to itextsharp anymay)

Comment: You can find a complete sample here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297745/itextsharp-pdfcopy-and-landscape-pages

Comment: How is this an answer when the code doesn't work as is?

Comment: GetPageSize doesn't exit