# itextsharp PdfCopy and landscape pages

Tags: itext, center, footer, landscape

I'm using itextsharp to join mutiple pdf documents and add a footer.
My code works fine - except for landscape pages - it isn't detecting the page rotation - the footer is not centerd for landscape:

```
    public static int AddPagesFromStream(Document document, PdfCopy pdfCopy, Stream m, bool addFooter, int detailPages, string footer, int footerPageNumOffset, int numPages, string pageLangString, string printLangString)
    {
        CreateFont();
        try
        {
            m.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var reader = new PdfReader(m);

            // get page count
            var pdfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
            var i = 0;

            // add pages
            while (i < pdfPages)
            {
                i++;

                // import page with pdfcopy
                var page = pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

                // get page center
                float posX;
                float posY;
                var rotation = page.BoundingBox.Rotation;
                if (rotation == 0 || rotation == 180)
                {
                    posX = page.Width / 2;
                    posY = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    posX = page.Height / 2;
                    posY = 20f;
                }

                var ps = pdfCopy.CreatePageStamp(page);
                var cb = ps.GetOverContent();

                // add footer
                cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
                var gs1 = new PdfGState {FillOpacity = 0.8f};
                cb.SetGState(gs1);
                cb.Rectangle(0, 0, document.PageSize.Width, 46f + posY);
                cb.Fill();

                // Text
                cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                cb.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 7);
                cb.BeginText();

                // create text
                var pages = string.Format(pageLangString, i + footerPageNumOffset, numPages);
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, printLangString, posX, 40f + posY, 0f);
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, footer, posX, 28f + posY, 0f);
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, pages, posX, 20f + posY, 0f);
                cb.EndText();

                ps.AlterContents();

                // add page to new pdf
                pdfCopy.AddPage(page);
            }

            // close PdfReader
            reader.Close();
            // return number of pages
            return i;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

How do I detect the page rotation (e.g. landscape) format in this case? The given example works for PdfReader but not for PdfCopy.

Edit:
Why do I need PdfCopy? I tried copying a word pdf export. Some word hyperlinks will not work when you try to copy pages with PdfReader. Only PdfCopy transfers all needed page informations.

Edit: (SOLVED)
You need to use reader.GetPageRotation(i);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use reader.GetPageRotation(i);

Solved code:

```
    public static int AddPagesFromStream(Document document, PdfCopy pdfCopy, Stream m, bool addFooter, int detailPages, string footer, int footerPageNumOffset, int numPages, string pageLangString, string printLangString)
    {
        CreateFont();
        try
        {
            m.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var reader = new PdfReader(m);

            // get page count
            var pdfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
            var i = 0;

            // add pages
            while (i < pdfPages)
            {
                i++;

                // import page with pdfcopy
                var page = pdfCopy.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

                // get page center
                float posX;
                float posY;
                var rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
                if (rotation == 0 || rotation == 180)
                {
                    posX = page.Width / 2;
                    posY = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    posX = page.Height / 2;
                    posY = 20f;
                }

                var ps = pdfCopy.CreatePageStamp(page);
                var cb = ps.GetOverContent();

                // add footer
                cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
                var gs1 = new PdfGState {FillOpacity = 0.8f};
                cb.SetGState(gs1);
                cb.Rectangle(0, 0, document.PageSize.Width, 46f + posY);
                cb.Fill();

                // Text
                cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
                cb.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 7);
                cb.BeginText();

                // create text
                var pages = string.Format(pageLangString, i + footerPageNumOffset, numPages);
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, printLangString, posX, 40f + posY, 0f);
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, footer, posX, 28f + posY, 0f);
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, pages, posX, 20f + posY, 0f);
                cb.EndText();

                ps.AlterContents();

                // add page to new pdf
                pdfCopy.AddPage(page);
            }

            // close PdfReader
            reader.Close();
            // return number of pages
            return i;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code sample, `page` is of type PdfImportedPage. You're asking for its Bounding Box. PdfImportedPage is of type PdfTemplate, so you're asking for the Bounding Box of an XObject. I doubt that will work.

You should ask the reader object for the rotation of the page. I guess you've already discovered that yourself because you say "The given example works for PdfReader, but not for PdfCopy".

Comment: Yes - I did. But I don't believe that I need to do this twice... One PdfReader to get the needed info and one PdfCopy to do the copying.